# Help with POW function in C++

Tags: c++, math

m having trouble with the pow function. The equation is `A=P*((1+R)/T)^T` were "^" is to the power of.  How would i use the pow function, i only see examples that are 4 to the 5th power, nothing like what i have to do

Comment: Can't you replace 4 by `((1+R)/T)` and 5 by `T` in that example you've seen?

Comment: I suggest you look a bit harder - SO users will not do your homework for you

Comment: Seconded... At the very least, don't tell us all that this is homework in the first place.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for interesting questions about programming languages. This is just a "help me support me plz" conversation, which is not what we are here for. Try a chatroom or forum instead.

Comment: @Mahnax: No, we _want_ people to be honest if their question is about homework. It helps us to close the question sooner.

Comment: @Tomalak: Actually, SO is a programming Q&A site.  Interesting is not a requirement as far as I am aware, but I see your point on this one.

Comment: @Tomalak I suppose that's true. But is a question being homework part of the criteria for closing a question?

Comment: @Mahnax: No, that bit was a joke. Sort of.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ok, please point me to the line in the FAQ were it states that mundane questions are not allowed.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm with Ed on your other post, just because something is uninteresting doesn't mean that it doesn't belong here.

Comment: When did I say that mundate or uninteresting questions are banned? I did not. Read my comments again. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming languages (and, yes, we prefer interesting ones). [This is _not_ a support website for every "my code doesn't work" problem that you can come up with.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105365/stack-overflow-has-too-many-too-localised-new-questions) "How do I use this function" (when the answer is in your favourite C++ book) is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it would simply be `A = pow((1+R)/T , T) * P;`

Comment: make sure that all your data-types are `double` or `float`, or else you will end up with an integer division problem in your base-value.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ function `std::pow` can be used as follows: if you write

```
std::pow(base, exponent)
```

the function computes `baseexponent`.  In your case, because you want to compute

```
A = P * ((1 + R) / T) ^ T
```

You might call the function like this:

```
A = P * std::pow((1 + R) / T, T);
```

Note that the second argument needn't be a constant; it can be any value that you'd like, even one you don't know until runtime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you use code tags rather than backticks, you can get rid of that ugly two-level effect in base/exponent (and use other markup within code as well). I've done that to show you how :-)

Comment: To whoever downvoted - can you please explain what's wrong with this answer?  I was under the impression that this was a well-written and thoughtful answer, and if there's something I can do to clarify it I would be happy to make the appropriate edits.

Comment: Upvoting since I agree with template that it's useful but also because I love annoying drive-by downvoters :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
P * pow((1+R)/T, T)
```

The second argument is the exponent (power) to raise the first argument to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `man pow` to see the usage

```
A = P * pow((1 + R) / T, T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
A = P * pow ((1 + R) / T, T)
```

or:

```
A = pow (P * (1 + R) / T, T)
```

depending on whether the power should include the multiplication by `P` or not.

I would suspect the former since exponentiation tends to have a higher priority in maths - i.e., `4x2` is `4(x2)`, not `(4x)2`.